# Upgrade the translations

Tags: localisation, l10n

Since Drupal 10 the documentation on updating the translations have changed:
https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal/#i18n

What exactly do I have to do to deploy a language other than english for an existing installation? Do I need the `cv core:install` command at all or are there other ways to tell the database there is a new language?

Answer (score 2):

1. Grab the localisation (l10n) files and unpack the l10n and sql subfolders into vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/

   You'll find the l10n files on the CiviCRM Download page or from https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-VERSION-l10n.tar.gz where VERSION is a recent version of CiviCRM.

**Example:**

```
cd /var/www/html/drupal10/
wget https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-5.27.2-l10n.tar.gz
tar -zxvf civicrm-5.27.2-l10n.tar.gz
cd civicrm/
cp -R l10n/ ../vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/
cp -R sql/ ../vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/
cd ..
rm -rf civicrm/
```

2. If you've done this correctly, you should end up with vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/l10n and vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/sql/

   You can remove any languages you don't need by deleting them before copying the l10n and sql folders.

Comment: This is what we have done so far. I thought there was a way now to store the l10n folder outside of civicrm-core, use languages without SQL files and and to download the latest version of a specific language. At least this is what the docs above look like.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I simply don't need any database upgrade. Just downloading the latest language file from https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-l10n-core/mo/de_DE/civicrm.mo and putting it into a l10n folder inside the Drupal private files directory does it for me. Not sure if the SQL files are required anymore.

The documentation ist a bit unclear to me about translation upgrading. Any clearification is welcome.